# Bluetooth applet disappeared from wingpanel

Tags: bluetooth

Tried to connect to bluetooth device today and noticed the icon was missing from wingpanel menubar.  Logout/in, reboot, killall wingpanel, no effect.  Bluetooth is gone.  Icon still appears in System Settings but says "Bluetooth is disabled"

Could a system update have broken it?  Wifi still works.  Which bluetooth manager does elementary OS use?

cheers

Comment: Have you looked inside `System Settings > Bluetooth`? Is it grayed out?

Comment: Yes, it's all greyed out.  Including the words "bluetooth is disabled"  See screenshot: http://i822.photobucket.com/albums/zz145/anjp/computer/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-06%20102054.png

Comment: I'm having a similar issue today, and I have had no joy. BT was working yesterday, and somehow the device is no longer showing as an active device. When I run `systemctl | grep bluetooth` shows service is running. When I run `dmesg | grep -i blue` I get all the messages I'd expect showing... but `hciconfig up` returns `Can't get device info: No such device` so somehow the hardware seems to be failing to initialize.