# How to debug bluetooth

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

I'm having regular issues with bluetooth and I could really use some tips on debugging this. Especially in areas it's different from Ubuntu.

I'm basically having this issue: [Bluetooth applet disappeared from wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/bluetooth-applet-disappeared-from-wingpanel).
But it's closed, since it should be reported in the issue queues, but the issue queues are quite full with unclear, never really resolved bluetooth related issues already. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos?field.searchtext=bluetooth+&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=

I'd like some tips on how I could properly contribute to one of those existing issues or open a new one.

What I already found out: 
`sudo service bluetooth status` for example indicates it's active (running) and restarting it doesn't help. 
All the UI in the Bluetooth panel in System Settings is disabled. 
Is there any way to check if the hardware was detected?
Is there any way to why the indicator isn't shown in Wingpanel?

```
$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    8.881963] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    8.881972] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.881974] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.881976] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.881979] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.887824] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    8.887827] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    8.887828] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    8.887829] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    8.887830] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    8.887831] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    8.887870] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    8.887885] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    8.887886] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   14.015183] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.015186] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
```

I have an up to date wingpanel bluetooth indicator:

```
$ sudo apt install wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth
wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth is already the newest version (2.0.1+r7
```

4+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1)

`$ rfkill list` doesn't include a bluetooth device, only one Wireless LAN device.

`$ lspci -v` doesn't include the word bluetooth.

bluez-tools's `hcitool dev` comes up empty.

`$ sudo lsusb | grep Bluetooth` returns nothing.

I'm running Loki on a XPS 15 (9550). 
It's bluetooth support is, not great, I had to manually download and copy a file to /lib/firmware/brcm/. (source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843)

**Update:** After another suspend later in the day (there have been several that day) suddenly the indicator appeared again.
Looks like the device is found again:

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    9C:B6:D0:D4:B2:52

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lsusb | grep Bluetooth` and `lspci -v | grep bluetooth` still return nothing.

`lshw` shows the bluetooth device, as one of the usb devices.

**Update #2:** I'm now in another state, where `rfkill list` lists the device, but `hcitool dev` lists no devices.

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    7.984254] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    7.984278] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.984281] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.984283] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.984287] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.991797] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    7.991799] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    7.991800] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    7.991800] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    7.991801] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    7.991802] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    7.991832] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    7.991849] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    7.991850] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    8.416132] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.416135] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.416138] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   85.464577] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   85.464587] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   85.464593] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[25148.516703] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[25150.520692] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2011 tx timeout
[25152.524724] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200b tx timeout
[25154.528734] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[25188.645084] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[25190.649112] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2011 tx timeout
[25192.653938] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200b tx timeout
[25194.657169] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[25204.401411] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[25206.405408] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
```

Comment: Check if the BT indicator is installed: `sudo apt install wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth`. That command should check and install it if it wasn't installed.

Comment: Thanks Maccer, I've tried that and it was already installed. (updated question with info). Do you know of a way to maybe completely stop wingpanel (prevent it from auto starting again) so that I can start wingpanel with debug logging?

Comment: You need to remove wingpanel from cerbere. Cerbere is an app that restarts wingpanel every time it crashes. You can do this in `elementary-tweaks` and probably from terminal, but i don't know the commands, sorry about that...

Comment: So, not really related to "how to debug", but when `rfkill list` includes the bluetooth device, I found I could sometimes revive it my doing `sudo modprobe -r btusb`, `sudo modprobe btusb`, `sudo service bluetooth restart`. This would re-add the icon to the wingpanel and enable usage again.

Comment: Check out [bluetoothctl](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/bluetooth/bluez/docs/reference/available-commands) From there you have access to the BlueZ stack and can see what is going on. I'm currently using it in an attempt to debug the deaded non-functioning bluetooth headset problem.

Answer (score 1):

Always look up for special menu option under the Bluetooth icon. Check on the connected device if there is a "systems Preferences Bluetooth > Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar." Hold down the shift-Option, click on the icon and find the "Debug" menu. Under the "Debug Option," you can now reset the Bluetooth module.